# interact.js - trello-style scrollable list of draggable items in a droparea

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, interact.js

Good morning, I created a simple trello-style interface.
Obviously I want to scroll the cards in a column: that works on a desktop pc with mouse wheel, but not on a smartphone using the touch scroll gesture.
I tried to use the "hold" param when creating draggables, nevertheless the scroll gesture didn't work.
How can I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling issue was caused by the CSS instruction "touch-action: none;" (it was present in the interact website's examples). Just removed it and now scroll works fine.